# How to dynamically manipulate canonical entity URLs

Tags: uri

I've got a project with a multi-user / multi-domain environment. There is one "main" portal like `www.myproject.com` and for every registered user with a specific custom permission `has_personal_subdomain` there is a subdomain and a theme with his username, e.g. user `johndoe` has a subdomain `johndoe.myproject.com` and this domain is using his custom theme `johndoe`.

I've already set up all the domains and the theme switching part. All editing/administrative actions are always done on the main portal domain, also users with personal subdomains work on the main portal domain.

The problem are the canonical entity links: When editing nodes, editing is always done in admin theme on the main portal domain, so of course all canonical entity links also point to the portal domain. E.g. for users with a personal subdomain, the canonical links to `www.myproject.com/node/123` or `www.myproject.com/my-node-url-alias`, but I want `johndoe.myproject.com/node/123` or `johndoe.myproject.com/my-node-url-alias`.

What is the best way to dynamically manipulate the canonical entity view links? I'm not asking for a complete code, I'm just looking for the best starting point/hook/event/service to inject my custom logic.

What I want to avoid:
Create a million custom hooks for `hook_menu_local_tasks_alter` AND `hook_form_alter` AND `hook_views_pre_render` AND whatever else...

I do not care about metatags, SEO, duplicate URLs,... I just want a better editor experience with personalized entity view links pointing to the correct subdomain using the correct theme.

I know there is the [OutboundPathProcessor](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21PathProcessor%21OutboundPathProcessorInterface.php/function/OutboundPathProcessorInterface%3A%3AprocessOutbound/8.2.x), but this seems a bit over the top, as I only want to change canonical URLs and none of the admin links.

Is there a service specifically for generating canonical URLs I can decorate?

Comment: What is wrong about OutboundPathProcessor? It's perfect for this use case because you can also add cache metadata to `$bubbleable_metadata`. Which is important when the URLs are dynamic.

Comment: Nothing wrong, it just seemed "oversized" for my use case. AFAIK OutboundPathProcessor runs on *every* link, and I only need to modify the subset of canonical entity URLs. But if the answer is "there is no better option than OutboundPathProcessor", I can live with it.

Comment: I don't see a performance impact, the result is cacheable the same way as if you would change it in a different place, if you find one. Another advantage, you can use the priority to position your path processor before or after other path processors, for example aliasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a service specifically for generating canonical URLs I can
> decorate?

Yes, for a route based handling of outgoing canonical links you can use [OutboundRouteProcessorInterface::processOutbound](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21RouteProcessor%21OutboundRouteProcessorInterface.php/function/OutboundRouteProcessorInterface%3A%3AprocessOutbound/9.0.x)

For example like core implements the dynamic route `<current>`.

*/core/lib/Drupal/Core/RouteProcessor/RouteProcessorCurrent.php*

```
  public function processOutbound($route_name, Route $route, array &$parameters, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {
    if ($route_name === '<current>') {
      if ($current_route = $this->routeMatch->getRouteObject()) {
        $requirements = $current_route->getRequirements();
        // Setting _method and _schema is deprecated since 2.7. Using
        // setMethods() and setSchemes() are now the recommended ways.
        unset($requirements['_method']);
        unset($requirements['_schema']);
        $route->setRequirements($requirements);

        $route->setPath($current_route->getPath());
        $route->setSchemes($current_route->getSchemes());
        $route->setMethods($current_route->getMethods());
        $route->setOptions($current_route->getOptions());
        $route->setDefaults($current_route->getDefaults());
        $parameters = array_merge($parameters, $this->routeMatch->getRawParameters()->all());
        if ($bubbleable_metadata) {
          $bubbleable_metadata->addCacheContexts(['route']);
        }
      }
      else {
        // If we have no current route match available, point to the frontpage.
        $route->setPath('/');
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This looked good, but I've failed to redirect accross domains with this service. So I've been going back to `OutboundPathProcessor` which allowed me to use $options['absolute'] = TRUE` and $options['base_url'] = $myhost`. I was unable to find something similar in `OutboundRouteProcessor`

Comment: I've answered this specific part of your question because you wanted to know which point/hook/event/service are available, not a complete solution. You can use both by the way, everything you put into the route object is available later in path processing. Starting with the canonical route here has the advantage that you can identify the route by its name without the need to resolve the path backwards.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally a working version using `OutboundPathProcessor`.

(I was not able to use `OutboundRouteProcessor` as suggested by @4k4 because I did not know how to create absolute, cross-domain URL manipulations in there).

This is my code (`wt_dgm` is my module name):

`wt_dgm.services.yml`
(I need `@current_user` and  `@config.factory` for my custom business logic, replace or remove by your needs)

```
  wt_dgm.path_outbound_host_processor:
    class: Drupal\wt_dgm\Path\OutboundHostProcessor
    arguments: [ '@current_user', '@config.factory']
    tags:
      - { name: path_processor_outbound, priority: 3000 }
```

`OutboundHostProcessor.php`

For my use case the key thing was using `$options['absolute']` and `$options['base_url']`, replace with your needs.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\wt_dgm\Path;

use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\OutboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class OutboundHostProcessor implements OutboundPathProcessorInterface {

  /**
   * @var $currentUser AccountProxyInterface
   */
  protected $currentUser;

  /**
   * @var $configFactory ConfigFactoryInterface
   */
  protected $configFactory;

  /**
   * @var $frontendCache array['username' => 'scheme:://username.dgmdomain.com']
   */
  protected $frontendCache;

  public function __construct(AccountProxyInterface $current_user, ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory) {
    $this->currentUser = $current_user;
    $this->configFactory = $config_factory;
    $this->frontendCache = [];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function processOutbound($path, &$options = array(), Request $request = NULL, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {
    try {
      $url = Url::fromUri('internal:' .  $path);
    }
    catch (\Throwable $throwable) {
      return $path;
    }
    if (!$url) {
      return $path;
    }

    $routeName = $url->getRouteName();
    if ($routeName != 'entity.node.canonical') {
      return $path;
    }

    $params = $url->getRouteParameters();
    if (!isset($params['node'])) {
      return $path;
    }

    $node = $params['node'];
    if (!($node instanceof Node) && is_numeric($node)) {
      $node = Node::load($node);
    }
    if (!($node instanceof Node)) {
      return $path;
    }

    $userDomain = $this->getCustomHost($request);
    if (!$userDomain) {
      return $path;
    }

    $options['absolute'] = TRUE;
    $options['base_url'] = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $userDomain;

    if ($bubbleable_metadata) {
      $bubbleable_metadata->addCacheContexts([
        'user',
      ]);
    }
    return $path;
  }

  protected function getCustomHost(Request $request) {
    // my custom logic here with current user etc
    if ($my_custom_yes) {
      return $myCustomHostname;
    }
    return NULL;
  }
}
```